# Extracting the values of a large JSON object into another object

Tags: javascript

I have the following object which i'm wanting to go through and extract specific keys into another object. I've tried the code below but i'm just getting undefined for all values.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -89.535,
                34.3654
            ]
        },
        "place_name": "University, Mississippi, United States",
        "properties": {
            "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",
            "countries": "Germany",
            "authorTitle": "Florian Mai"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                10.14,
                54.33
            ]
        },
        "place_name": "24105, Kiel, Schleswig-Holstein, Germany",
        "properties": {
            "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",
            "countries": "Germany",
            "authorTitle": "Iacopo Vagliano"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -89.535,
                34.3654
            ]
        },
        "place_name": "University, Mississippi, United States",
        "properties": {
            "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",
            "countries": "Germany",
            "authorTitle": "Lukas Galke"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -1.898631,
                50.744119
            ]
        },
        "place_name": "University Roundabout, Bournemouth, Bournemouth, BH12 5EQ, United Kingdom",
        "properties": {
            "title": "An update on the 2014 report: \"Review of Recirculation Aquaculture System Technologies and their Commercial Application\"",
            "countries": "United Kingdom",
            "authorTitle": "David Fletcher"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -2.89,
                43.29
            ]
        },
        "place_name": "48160, Derio, Bizkaia, Spain",
        "properties": {
            "title": "An update on the 2014 report: \"Review of Recirculation Aquaculture System Technologies and their Commercial Application\"",
            "countries": "Spain",
            "authorTitle": "Maddi Badiola"
        }
    }
]
}
```

I want to go through it and extract the title and authortitle, and add each title and authortitle to a new object entry

What i've tried

```
extractedValues1 = business1.features.map(({ authorTitle, title }) => ({ authorTitle, title }));




  testObject = {
    object: extractedValues1
  }
```

What i want to achieve

```
testObject = {

    0:{
      authorTitle:'Florian Mai',
     title:'Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation'
     }
     1:{
       authorTitle:'Iacopo Vagliano'
       Title:'Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation'
      }
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `reduce` and the third param from the handler, which is the current index.

In order to assign the index as a property name, you can use a capability called `computed-property-name`.

```
extractedValues1 = business1.features.reduce((a, { authorTitle, title }, i) => 
        Object.assign(a, {[i]: { authorTitle, title }}), Object.create(null));
```

```js
var obj = {  "type": "FeatureCollection",  "features": [{      "type": "Feature",      "geometry": {        "type": "Point",        "coordinates": [-89.535,          34.3654        ]      },      "place_name": "University, Mississippi, United States",      "properties": {        "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",        "countries": "Germany",        "authorTitle": "Florian Mai"      }    },    {      "type": "Feature",      "geometry": {        "type": "Point",        "coordinates": [          10.14,          54.33        ]      },      "place_name": "24105, Kiel, Schleswig-Holstein, Germany",      "properties": {        "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",        "countries": "Germany",        "authorTitle": "Iacopo Vagliano"      }    },    {      "type": "Feature",      "geometry": {        "type": "Point",        "coordinates": [-89.535,          34.3654        ]      },      "place_name": "University, Mississippi, United States",      "properties": {        "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",        "countries": "Germany",        "authorTitle": "Lukas Galke"      }    },    {      "type": "Feature",      "geometry": {        "type": "Point",        "coordinates": [-1.898631,          50.744119        ]      },      "place_name": "University Roundabout, Bournemouth, Bournemouth, BH12 5EQ, United Kingdom",      "properties": {        "title": "An update on the 2014 report: \"Review of Recirculation Aquaculture System Technologies and their Commercial Application\"",        "countries": "United Kingdom",        "authorTitle": "David Fletcher"      }    },    {      "type": "Feature",      "geometry": {        "type": "Point",        "coordinates": [-2.89,          43.29        ]      },      "place_name": "48160, Derio, Bizkaia, Spain",      "properties": {        "title": "An update on the 2014 report: \"Review of Recirculation Aquaculture System Technologies and their Commercial Application\"",        "countries": "Spain",        "authorTitle": "Maddi Badiola"      }    }  ]}

let extractedValues1 = obj.features.reduce((a, { properties: { authorTitle, title }} , i) => 
            Object.assign(a, {[i]: { authorTitle: authorTitle, title }}), Object.create(null));
            
console.log(extractedValues1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Without numerical value

```js
var obj = {  "type": "FeatureCollection",  "features": [{      "type": "Feature",      "geometry": {        "type": "Point",        "coordinates": [-89.535,          34.3654        ]      },      "place_name": "University, Mississippi, United States",      "properties": {        "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",        "countries": "Germany",        "authorTitle": "Florian Mai"      }    },    {      "type": "Feature",      "geometry": {        "type": "Point",        "coordinates": [          10.14,          54.33        ]      },      "place_name": "24105, Kiel, Schleswig-Holstein, Germany",      "properties": {        "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",        "countries": "Germany",        "authorTitle": "Iacopo Vagliano"      }    },    {      "type": "Feature",      "geometry": {        "type": "Point",        "coordinates": [-89.535,          34.3654        ]      },      "place_name": "University, Mississippi, United States",      "properties": {        "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",        "countries": "Germany",        "authorTitle": "Lukas Galke"      }    },    {      "type": "Feature",      "geometry": {        "type": "Point",        "coordinates": [-1.898631,          50.744119        ]      },      "place_name": "University Roundabout, Bournemouth, Bournemouth, BH12 5EQ, United Kingdom",      "properties": {        "title": "An update on the 2014 report: \"Review of Recirculation Aquaculture System Technologies and their Commercial Application\"",        "countries": "United Kingdom",        "authorTitle": "David Fletcher"      }    },    {      "type": "Feature",      "geometry": {        "type": "Point",        "coordinates": [-2.89,          43.29        ]      },      "place_name": "48160, Derio, Bizkaia, Spain",      "properties": {        "title": "An update on the 2014 report: \"Review of Recirculation Aquaculture System Technologies and their Commercial Application\"",        "countries": "Spain",        "authorTitle": "Maddi Badiola"      }    }  ]}

let extractedValues1 = obj.features.map(({ properties: { authorTitle, title }}) => 
            ({ authorTitle: authorTitle, title }));
            
console.log(extractedValues1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The properties you're looking for (`authorTitle` and `title`) are inside the `properties` property on the parent object, so you have to go through `properties`:

```
const arr = features.map(
  ({ properties: { authorTitle, title }}) => ({ authorTitle, title })
);
const output = { ...arr };
```

```js
const features = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-89.535,
        34.3654
      ]
    },
    "place_name": "University, Mississippi, United States",
    "properties": {
      "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",
      "countries": "Germany",
      "authorTitle": "Florian Mai"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        10.14,
        54.33
      ]
    },
    "place_name": "24105, Kiel, Schleswig-Holstein, Germany",
    "properties": {
      "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",
      "countries": "Germany",
      "authorTitle": "Iacopo Vagliano"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-89.535,
        34.3654
      ]
    },
    "place_name": "University, Mississippi, United States",
    "properties": {
      "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",
      "countries": "Germany",
      "authorTitle": "Lukas Galke"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-1.898631,
        50.744119
      ]
    },
    "place_name": "University Roundabout, Bournemouth, Bournemouth, BH12 5EQ, United Kingdom",
    "properties": {
      "title": "An update on the 2014 report: \"Review of Recirculation Aquaculture System Technologies and their Commercial Application\"",
      "countries": "United Kingdom",
      "authorTitle": "David Fletcher"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-2.89,
        43.29
      ]
    },
    "place_name": "48160, Derio, Bizkaia, Spain",
    "properties": {
      "title": "An update on the 2014 report: \"Review of Recirculation Aquaculture System Technologies and their Commercial Application\"",
      "countries": "Spain",
      "authorTitle": "Maddi Badiola"
    }
  }
];



const arr = features.map(
  ({ properties: { authorTitle, title }}) => ({ authorTitle, title })
);
const output = { ...arr }
console.log(output);
```

It's a little bit odd to have a non-array object with only numerical properties which aren't sparse, though - you might consider just using the `.map`ped array alone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yea it does seem odd, how could i extract the values without adding each one to a numerical value?

Comment: You mean, just `<value>`, rather than `0: <value>`? By using an array instead of an object

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop to loop through the object and add the properties to a new object.

```js
var obj = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-89.535,
          34.3654
        ]
      },
      "place_name": "University, Mississippi, United States",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",
        "countries": "Germany",
        "authorTitle": "Florian Mai"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          10.14,
          54.33
        ]
      },
      "place_name": "24105, Kiel, Schleswig-Holstein, Germany",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",
        "countries": "Germany",
        "authorTitle": "Iacopo Vagliano"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-89.535,
          34.3654
        ]
      },
      "place_name": "University, Mississippi, United States",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",
        "countries": "Germany",
        "authorTitle": "Lukas Galke"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-1.898631,
          50.744119
        ]
      },
      "place_name": "University Roundabout, Bournemouth, Bournemouth, BH12 5EQ, United Kingdom",
      "properties": {
        "title": "An update on the 2014 report: \"Review of Recirculation Aquaculture System Technologies and their Commercial Application\"",
        "countries": "United Kingdom",
        "authorTitle": "David Fletcher"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-2.89,
          43.29
        ]
      },
      "place_name": "48160, Derio, Bizkaia, Spain",
      "properties": {
        "title": "An update on the 2014 report: \"Review of Recirculation Aquaculture System Technologies and their Commercial Application\"",
        "countries": "Spain",
        "authorTitle": "Maddi Badiola"
      }
    }
  ]
}
var expectedOutput = {};

obj.features.forEach((e, i) => {
  expectedOutput[i] = { "authorTitle": e.properties.authorTitle, "title":e.properties.title };
});

console.log(expectedOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used map javascript function to extract the author and title

see code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hebvsu?embed=1&file=index.js

Comment: Could you possibly show me how to do this without the need to add a numerical id for each addition? I've been told an array would achieve this